# How do I work with JavaFX in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-installer, javafx-2

I have installed `jdk1.7.0_15`.

[JavaFX's download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) says  the following:

> JavaFX 2.2.7 contains the latest security fixes and is co-bundled with
>   the latest JDK 7 for Windows, Mac and Linux.
>   Download Java SE 7 with JavaFX 2.2.7

Like a good noob, I followed the instructions and installed the JDK. Now when I look for `jfxrt.jar` file that I can import to Eclipse as a user library, I can not find it. There are a few other `JavaFX` related libraries in JDK's `lib` folder but I do not understand what to import next.

Most of the tutorials on Google, including the one by Java, are very old.
Please help me get started with JavaFX

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241525/how-to-use-javafx-2-sdk-in-eclipse/ :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend using [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html).

e(fx)clipse is a plugin to assist JavaFX development in Eclipse which will fix your classpath issue and provide you with many other useful features as well as step by step documentation and code completion assistance.

Answer (score 19):

Great question. I remember having the same problem when I started. Here is a little step by step guide.

1) Make a new JavaFx project (This is actually the same as a Java project, it just comes with a more suitable skeleton)
2) If you're getting errors like 'Can't find javafx.application' add the jfxrt.jar by right clicking on the libraries and select 'Add folder/Jar' You will have to browse to your jdk folder and find jfxrt.jar. Here is where it is located in my jdk:
`/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar`

3) For the third step I suggest checking out [this example.](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) This example comes with sample code and I used it to copy and paste till I got a little more comfortable in javafx.

Comment: Step 2 is not needed if you are using e(fx)clipse and your project points to the appropriate JDK7/JRE7.