# Auto-completion for JavaFX not working in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

While trying out JavaFX, I'm currently having problems with auto-completion. I have a standard-maven project with Java 8 set as source and target:

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This is correctly recognized, I can use auto-completion for Stream API and so on.

Some threads, e.g. [How to Use JavaFX in Eclipse Swing Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579786/how-to-use-javafx-in-eclipse-swing-project), show that jfxrt is necessary for using JavaFX. Eclipse uses the correct JVM under /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ and it does find the correct jfxrt.jar in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar. If I manually open (in the Package Explorer) JRE System Library -> jfxrt.jar -> javafx.embed.swing I see JFXPanel laying there as it should.

Nevertheless, when I hit Strg + Space after the input of `JFXPanel` it only tells me to create a class with this name. Even if I write `import javafx.embed.swing` it only suggests me to write `import javafx.embed.swing.*` instead of any class in this package.

This behaviour seems very awkward to me. Can anyone tell me, why eclipse isn't able to complete this or what I could do to prevent this problem from happening?

Comment: For some reason the JavaFX API in Eclipse is marked as "Forbidden" through the `**/*` access rule (go Build Path for a project and select Libraries -> JRE/or JDK). Try [efxclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but in Configure -> Build Path -> Access rules there is nothing defined (it says 'No rules defined' and is empty). Is there any way to mark the JavaFX API as not forbidded without using efxclipse?

Comment: I would be interested in that too :)

Comment: Edit it? But really this NOT eclipse fault anything on the ext-classpath is NOT public API and Eclipse hides it. Please note thate efxclipse will make your live so much easier e.g. with advanced CSS-Tooling, ... but anyways editing the rules should give you access to JavaFX

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties -> Java Build Path -> [] -> JRE System Library. Check whether you are using a jdk and not a jre. If using a jre switch to a jdk and the issue will be resolved