# Trying to write Java program to play mp3 file

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to write a program that plays an mp3 file. For some reason, I am getting the error "`package.javafx.scene.media does not exist.`" How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You need `e(fx)clipse` or you need to add the `jfxrt.jar` to your classpath. It comes with your JDK.
[How do I work with JavaFX in Eclipse Juno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149547/how-do-i-work-with-javafx-in-eclipse-juno) should sort it out for you. NetBeans and IntelliJ come with built-in support for JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

You could also work with [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/) as JavaFX is already included there. It also provides a lot of improvements on JavaFX components.