# What do I need to change in my Eclipse setup to import and run javafx?

Tags: java, import, javafx

[I'm taking this Oracle tutorial and on the page about Anonymous classes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) In it, is an example of a Say "Hello World" button.

I'm getting import javafx cannot be resolved errors.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

What do I need to change in my Eclipse configuration to run this?

Comment: have you downloaded and configured the JavaFX SDK?

Comment: I'm new to Java and programming in general. I have no idea what "downloaded and configured JavaFX SDK" means. It looks like I have a lot of digging and research ahead of me. Ugh.

Comment: I'm new to java, but if you click the link in my answer it should show you how to download and configure JavaFX if you just scroll down to the section about running JavaFX on Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. I'll delete this one. I just don't understand anything on the one you linked...I get a "this page has moved" message on your first link...

Comment: I mean't look at the link that is at the bottom of my answer. Sorry for not clarifying. "Referenced: http://www.packtpub.com/article/installing-and-setting-javafx-netbeans-and-eclipse-ide "

Comment: I'm stuck on step 3. It says add http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html as the plug in site. The link says the page has been moved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58459/discussion-between-photographybum-and-stacym).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this link to download and install JavaFX 2: http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-lazy

Comment: Thanks, I found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241525/how-to-use-javafx-2-sdk-in-eclipse. Down the rabbit hole I go!

Comment: The information in this answer is obsolete and misleading as it refers to JavaFX 1.x technology which is not available anymore.  The preferred way for an Eclipse user to use JavaFX is to use the [e(fx)clipse toolset](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) as recommended in the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: @jewelsea Answer has been fixed.